# prolog:search in binary search tree

Tags: prolog

i need to covert list to binary search tree ,then search about range of ages in this tree and return the  a list contain these values, and also return number of checks in order to build the output list .

i spend two days trying do this but it always return false

here my last code that i reach it with help of mbratch:

```
 my_list( [[30,'john'], [58,'alex'], [14,'randy'], [65,'shawn'], [67,'jack']] ).

 construct(L,T) :- construct(L,T,nil).

 construct([],T,T).
 construct([N|Ns],T,T0) :- add(N,T0,T1), construct(Ns,T,T1).

 add(X, nil, node(X, nil, nil)).
 add(X, node(Root, L, R),node(Root, L1, R)) :- X @< Root, add(X, L, L1).
 add(X, node(Root, L, R),node(Root, L, R1)) :- X @> Root, add(X, R, R1).

 findInRange(R1, R2, T, S, N) :- find(R1, R2, T, S, N),!.

 find(_R1,_R2, nil, [], 0).
 find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), S, N) :-
    R1 =< Age,R2 >= Age, % is the age OK (in range), if it is check left and 
    find(R1, R2, L, LL, NL),
    find(R1,R2,R,LR,NR),
    append([[Age,Name]],LL,X),
    append(X,LR,S),
    N is NL+NR+1.
 find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), [], 0) :-
    Age > R2;Age<R1.               % if the age is greater than R2, return []
 find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), LL, N) :-
    R1 < Age, % if the age is bigger than R1 search the left tree return LL
    find(R1,R2,L,LL,NL),
    N is NL+1.
 find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), LR, N) :-
    R2 > Age, % if the age smaller than R1 search the right tree return LR
    find(R1,R2,R,LR,NR),
    N is NR+1.
```

and here is my query :

```
     my_list(Z), construct(Z, T), findInRange(11, 15, T, S, N).
```

it should retufn [[14,'randy']] and number of checks.

Why does it return empty list and N=0 ?

Comment: I don't think if you run the code you are showing above that it returns false. What do you get if you try it?

Comment: it give me warning  evaluable `find(_G8472,_G8473,node([_G8482,_G8485],_G8479,_G8480),_G8475,_G8476):_G8482' does not exist ,and it return false.

Comment: If you run the code above it should generate an error since it's not valid Prolog syntax. Are you sure what you're running is what you have in your problem above?

Comment: try this query: my_list(Z),construct(Z,T). Whats the value of T?

Comment: @ssBarBee it give me
Z = [[30, john], [58, alex], [14, randy], [65, shawn], [67, jack]],
T = node([30, john], node([14, randy], nil, nil), node([58, alex], nil, node([65, shawn], nil, node([67, jack], nil, nil)))) .

Comment: @mbratch it give warning ,and it return false.

Comment: When I run your code, I get the following error, which is what I would expect: `uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,(:)/2),(<)/2)`. The reason is that the line `find(R1,R2,node([Age,Name],L,R), S, N):Age<R1 ;Age>R2,` is invalid prolog syntax (the `:` is inappropriate). I think the code you're running and describing results for doesn't match the code in your problem statement.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832162/prologi-need-to-search-in-binary-search-tree-in-given-range

Comment: In SWI Prolog, the error is: `ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

Comment: i run the code above again it give me false i am using SWI prolog

Comment: i am sure it give me false i made new file and paste the code above
and it give me it give me warning evaluable `find(_G8472,_G8473,node([_G8482,_G8485],_G8479,_G8480),_G8475,_G8476):_G8482' does not exist 

and it return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick. I ran the query you posted and got `S = [[30, john], [14, randy]]`.

```
my_list( [[30,'john'], [58,'alex'], [14,'randy'], [65,'shawn'], [67,'jack']] ).

construct(L,T) :- construct(L,T,nil).
construct([],T,T).
construct([N|Ns],T,T0) :- add(N,T0,T1),construct(Ns,T,T1).

add(X, nil, node(X, nil, nil)).
add(X, node(Root, L, R),node(Root, L1, R)) :- X @< Root, add(X, L, L1).
add(X, node(Root, L, R),node(Root, L, R1)) :- X @> Root, add(X, R, R1).

findInRange(R1, R2, T, S, N) :- find(R1, R2, T, S, N),!.

find(_R1,_R2, nil, [], 0).
find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), S, N) :-
            R1 =< Age,R2 >= Age, % is the age OK (in range), if it is check left and right side
            find(R1, R2, L, LL, NL),
            find(R1,R2,R,LR,NR),
            append([[Age,Name]| LL],LR,S),
            N is NL+NR+1.

find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), LL, N) :-
            Age > R2, % if the age is bigger than R2 search the left tree return LL
            find(R1,R2,L,LL,NL),
            N is NL+1.
find(R1, R2, node([Age,Name],L,R), LR, N) :-
            R1 > Age, % if the age smaller than R1 search the right tree return LR
            find(R1,R2,R,LR,NR),
            N is NR+1.
```

Comment: why i get number of check N=5?
i think it must be less than that?

Comment: We have 5 nodes in tree, so we compare the range for every node to see if it fits? It natural to have 5 checks?

Comment: so number of check in binary search tree is will be like a list?

Comment: i enter the input as a list and i get 5 checks is this make sense?

Comment: thank you for help, but i enter the input as a list and i get 5 checks is this make sense?

Comment: I updated the answer cause it didn't make any sense to me aswell:) Sorry if I mislead you...

Comment: @user3141021 now that someone has completed the answer for you, I think you need to work to understand the changes we discussed in the comments of the prior duplicate post you made, plus what ssBarBee has added. So far I see mostly evidence that you have the answer you wanted but without understanding. You need to learn basic Prolog terminology and syntax to start out.

Comment: @mbratch Can you give me your opinion about the code I wrote? Cause I'm learning myself, so it'd be nice to have someone more experienced review it ( if it's not trouble ).

Comment: @mbratch i am new in prolog so i need to complete this code first, then i want to learn prolog to became professional thank you all guys.

Comment: @user3141021 the point of this exercise is to be learning. You don't do assignments and then learn later. The exercise is for the purpose of learning. That's the way it works if you want to become a professional.

Comment: @mbratch you right but i have not time i have a lot of courses and exams in this month

Comment: @ssBarBee for this particular scenario, using the structure the OP already established, you didn't need to add the extra `append` in the `find` clause. Just one is fine. In other words, `append([X], Y, Z)` is the same as using `[X|Y]` in place of `Z`, so you don't need to do `append` to achieve that. The OPs original code was fine. Also, assuming a balanced binary tree, you don't need a separate `find` clause for `R1 > Age` and a recursive `find` call. If `Age < R1` then there shouldn't be any "hits" in the recursive call. So the `find` clause with `R2 < Age` would have `R2 < Age ; R1 > Age`.

Comment: @user3141021 stated in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3141021, for the record, I went through to getting my BS in Mathematics and MS in Computer Engineering. I also minored in Music. I took a heavy course load. We didn't have internet access then, so we achieved our assignments and passed our exams without asking people online to just give us answers to problems. So take heart, it is possible to do. :)

Comment: @user3141021 Case Institute of Technology, Cleveland OH. Longer ago than I care to think about. :)

Comment: how u study MS in Computer Engineering and your BS not Engineering?

Comment: @user3141021 each degree has it's level of required coursework. I took both Mathematics and some elective Computer Engineering/Science classes as an undergraduate.

Comment: Ok that is good,last thing i see your comment about the append but i am not understand what you mean?

Comment: @ssBarBee how i could return just S=['john','randy'] as output?

Comment: @ssBarBee just the names without the ages?

Comment: @mbratch look at the code above,i i edit as you say but it does not work why?

Comment: @ssBarBee look at my code above,there is an error in some query why??

Comment: @user3141021 that doesn't match at all what I suggested.